# What are the practical uses of DFS and BFS?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I had this question asked in the interview today. I told them its traversal and DFS can be used to see if the graph is connected. They said it was too simple.

What are some more important practical uses of DFS and BFS?

Comment: Wikipedia pages for [`BFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Applications) and [`DFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Applications) have *Applications* section.

Comment: Pham Trung. How come there's no correct answer? DFS and BFS do have practical applications, don't they?

Comment: How can you mark an answer as correct if there is so many correct answers, furthermore this question will never has a precise and full answer.

Comment: But there is a correct answer. There are applications of DFS and BFS. If your logic is to be followed, then a lot of most popular questions on SO must be considered off-topic.

Comment: Also, different people answer with different perspectives and it will definitely help the asker to better understand the question.

Comment: @MagicManSuperMan Please be understanding, yes, it can have many correct answers, but this website try to avoid discussion type of answer, to my knowledge. You can try Quora instead? Use the right tool for the right job, that's my view :)

Comment: I have to back up @PhamTrung on this. There is no clear best answer to this question. That does not mean it isn't an interesting question, it just doesn't work too well in the SO format. Note that many old questions on this site are closed as too broad, but are kept there for historical reasons.

Answer (score 7):

On a lighter note. This always comes to my mind when I hear DFS or BFS.

*Note: This does not provide the direct answer to your question.*

[image]

Comment: @MrSmith42, Yup its really great for understanding too. :)

Comment: ha ha , this is an awesome fun example.

Answer (score 4):

BFS :

1. Minimum Spanning Tree or shortest path
2. Peer to peer networking
3. Crawler for search engine
4. Social network websites - to find people with a given distance k from a person using BFS till k levels.

DFS :

1. Minimum Spanning Tree
2. Topological sorting
3. To solve puzzle/maze which has one solution

Comment: It's funny how people sometimes use the terms "real-world" and practical, and then go on to list topics in computing that they think apply. I would have thought answers like "building bridges that can hold more weight, " or "increasing the efficiency of fuel consumption for aircraft" would be better (but inaccurate in this case) examples.

Answer (score 3):

Here some points which come in my mind while reading your question:

**DFS:**

- not usable on infinite trees (because you might go down an infinite branch). Or if there are cycles in your search graph you must take precaution to avoid running in a cycle forever.
- you will most likely not find the nearest solution first
- you need only O(depth) memory

**BFS**

- the first solution you find is one of the nearest ones
- you will need quite a lot of memory, because the search tree might get very broad already at quite little depth.
- works on infinite trees and cyclic structures without any precaution

Of cause you will find much more on wikipedia

[BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

[DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: But if you have a node with an infinite number of children, BFS has the same drawback as DFS.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: you are right. But I haven't seen this in real  live yet. Have you got an example?

Comment: No, but then I don't have an example of an infinite depth tree, either. But consider something like a [pairing heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_heap), in which the root node could have a very large (essentially infinite) number of children. That can happen if you keep adding nodes without ever doing a *delete-min*.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Infinite depth is often the result of a too big state space to track cycles. E.g. In chess (without time limit) there does not really exists a game with infinite number of moves, but for practical reasons you might not want make the effort of detecting cycles.